# Until EOF syntax in C

Tags: c

I can scan until end of file using these codes:

```
while(scanf("%d",&a) != EOF) //. . .

while(scanf("%d",&a) == 2) // . . .

while(scanf("%d",&a)+1) // . . .
```

**My question is pretty clear:** What can I use ***instead*** of these codes?

Comment: Your second example has an error. It should be `==` instead of `=`. Also `+1` seems terribly confusing. I think the first case is the best of all three.

Comment: What can you use instead of this code in order to do what?

Comment: Are you just interested in alternatives for the sake of learning, or is there a specific concern you are trying to address?

Comment: ...+1 is not only confusing, it is incorrect. `EOF` is guaranteed to be negative, but not to be `-1`. (The fact that it happens to be -1 on your platform is irrelevant.)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is non of them.

The last is wrong as it assumes `EOF` is -1, which is not necessarily true. The second is wrong because `scanf` can never return `2` with that format string. The first one has a shot, but is not that good either.

If you loop `while(scanf("%d",&a) != EOF)`, then the loop terminates at end of file (or file-read errors). However, if for non-file-error reasons `scanf` fails, you do not detect it. One such error is meeting input that is not convertible by `%d`, such as a letter in the alphabet.

`scanf` returns the number of items it successfully reads. In other words, if you have `N` of `%...`s (excluding `%*...`s), then `scanf` should return `N`, otherwise there's an error. This error could be bad input, file read error or end of file.

So the safest way of checking if `scanf` succeeded is checking if it could read as many items as you asked it to.  In your case, this is:

```
while (scanf("%d",&a) == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do without checking EOF. Otherwise it will wait for another input. Suppose you want to take input while there is a file containing input. So easiest way is the first one, checking that if you are in the 'End of File'. Now, what `scanf` returns. It will return the input it has taken successfully. If it can scan one integer like `scanf("%d",&a)`, it will return 1. `scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d",&a,&a,&a,&a,&a,&a)` this will return 6. So by `==` you are checking if it is taking correct amount of input every time. So if the amount is not correct you can exit or break like `if(scanf("%d",&a)!=1) break`.

Your `while(scanf("%d",&a) == 2)` is wrong, it should be `while(scanf("%d",&a) == 1)`

`while(scanf("%d",&a)+1)` is it Ok? I don't think so... `while(scanf("%d",&a)-1)` may be ok.

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` will return 0 (bad input),1 (good), or EOF (no more input).  Handle accordingly.

```
int result;
while ((result = scanf("%d",&a)) == 1) {
  Handle_int(a);
}
if (result == 0) {
  Handle_BadData();  // Maybe someone typed non-numeric text
}
else if (result == EOF) {
  Handle_EOForIOError();
}
else {
  ; // This should never happen -else condition not needed
}
```

Do not assume `EOF` is -1, but it is negative.